# Editing an Excel file and saving it to a new file with Python

Tags: python, excel, edit, xlrd, xlutils

I want to go into my current folder and edit whatever files is in the folder with the string "test" onto cell 0,0 and then save it as book1.xlsx but my code is giving me an error. Can anyone help?

```
import xlrd
import os
import glob
from xlutils.copy import copy

fileDir = os.getcwd()
fileLocation = glob.glob("*.xlsx")



x = copy(fileLocation)
x.get_sheet(0).write(0,0,"test")
x.save('book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please add the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

glob.glob("*.xlsx") must return a list, so I think the error is on the copy statement.

Try with :

```
x = copy(fileLocation[0])
```